# Why doesn't Ruby's IRB print_print correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pretty-print, irb

Using `Rails 4.0.4` and `Ruby 2.1.1`, and inside of an model's controller I want to use `pp` to check out an object. I have a call to `debugger` to pause execution and look around. However, `pp` seems to be truncating the out put of things and not allowing them to show up on multiple lines:

```
>pp ShopOrder

#<Shoporder id: 64, order_id: "142949823232-3232353652342", shop_id: 1, order_
status: "Completed", order_tests_queued: "2014-04-02 18:19:36", shipped_time: 
nil, shipping_address_name: "John Doe", total: 43.9, created_time: "2014-04-02
03:04:20", raw: "{\"order_id\":\"142949823232-3232353652342\",\"order_sta...">

 ( ^^ I did not truncated this for the question, it just ends this way ^^ )
```

I'm used to `pp` normally formatting this nicely and displaying it on multiple lines, more similar to what happens when using `y ShopOrder` to get the nicely formatted `to_yaml` output:

```
--- !ruby/object:Shoporder
attributes:
  id: 64
  order_id: 142949823232-3232353652342
  shop_id: 1
  order_status: Completed
  order_tests_queued: 2014-04-02 18:19:36.498044000 Z
  shipped_time: 
  shipping_address_name: John Doe
  total: 43.9
  created_time: 2014-04-02 03:04:20.000000000 Z
  ... (output continues correctly but has been truncated for this example )
```

Echo is enabled as `irb_context.echo` returns `true`

`y` and `to_yaml` are fine but at times I'd also like to be able to use `pp`

Why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use Awesome Print instead

It is (strangely) intended behavior for large objects.

Don't use `pp` from `pretty_print` use `ap` from `awesome_print`

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves `pp` relies on a `pretty_print` method for its output. Perhaps something is defining that in your models, or overriding it and truncating the string returned by `super`.

Comment: I'm new to ruby - how can I debug this? In bash I know you can use something like `\curl` ( with a slash ) to prevent aliases from being used...

Comment: Tough one… :-| Personally, I'd search my project and the various gems I use for occurrences of `pretty_print`, and go through them one by one starting by the most likely culprit. (There might admittedly be better ways.)